# How to speed up the search by the overpass-api

Tags: overpass-api

I'm new with OverPass API. I need to find a street in a particular city in a particular country. Here's a query that I created:

```
[out:xml]
area[name="Беларусь"]->.a;
(rel(area.a)[name="Ганцевичи"];
 way(area.a)[name="Ганцевичи"];);
map_to_area -> .b;
(way(area.b)["highway"~".*"]["name"~"веры хоружей",i];
._;>;)->.c;
.c out;
```

waiting for results takes a very long time. how to speed up the process, it is possible that something is wrong in the query?

Comment: Are you sure about street name? "веры хоружей" bring only a bus stop node in OSM.